# How do you say "what do you care?" in japanese?

Tags: phrase-requests

How do you say "what do you care?" in japanese, as if you were telling someone not to interfere in someone else's business in a harsh way to tell him so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

君には関係ないでしょう?＝It isn't related to you, is it? ~ None of your business.